# LIT + Casein + authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, rails-i18n

I'm trying to integrate LIT https://github.com/prograils/lit  in a casein CMS install https://github.com/russellquinn/casein

Casein uses authlogic for user authentication, to use the same sessions, casein can be configured to use the app's authentication function.  It gives the example ":authenticate_user! "

```
# in config/lit.rb
# Which authentication function to use (ie. :authenticate_user!)? When set to
# `nil` will let everyone in.
Lit.authentication_function = :authenticate_user!
```

It seems like I should be familiar with this authentication function's name, I tried to search the casein and authlogic source without luck.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, Lit seems like a really nice idea, but it's so awfully heavy, takes more ressources than everything else in my application all together, will look for another UI to edit my translations.